# Asp Web API Basic Auth not working when installed in iis server

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api

**Asp Web API** is working in VS Studio (normal get and service call with Auth) . But When i  install same service (Copy and paste Bin) in IIS Server . Only Normal get data function is working , when try to call service call with Auth Getting **401 Error**.
[image]

Link i used to add Basic Auth in Web API :[basic-authentication-in-web-api](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/basic-authentication-in-web-api/)

Both Anonymous Authentication and Basic Authentication  enabled in IIS.

Any idea ?

**Update**

Mycroft Doc mark http call as not secure , so is it getting blocked ?
[image: image basic-authentication]

Comment: As long as you enable anonymous authentication, you only get anonymous.

Comment: @LexLi yes but why service call with Basic auth falling ? Any more config missing ?

Comment: 404 can be caused by tons of factors, so you'd better get started from FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: I have a feeling the issue isn't related to auth but rather the discoverability of the endpoint. It's possible the path is incorrect or it's not being hosted

Comment: You can refer to the document to republish your asp.net web api: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/publish-and-host-Asp-Net-web-api/

Comment: @LexLi Sorry , i was wrong not 404 , it was 401 error code returned from server

Comment: FRT works for all kinds of error codes, so let it tell you what's the cause.